# How to give extra kwargs to a modelform field - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a simple cropping utility using jQuery and Jcrop (would be inside a modelform).
Initially I had this in my models:

```
photo = CustomImageField(null=True, allowed_types=['type:image'],
                         width=960, height=340)
```

However now I have Jcrop data (that I would like to insert for 'width' and 'height' parameters) in my main.js and would have to be sent to Django.
To do that, I created a hidden form field in my modelform and I populate it with jQuery after the user has created a selection (a default is also provided, in case the user does not select anything).

I was thinking that maybe I could add the extra keyword arguments when I override the form `save()` method, but
a) does it pass the kwargs to the CustomImageField?
b) I have no idea (syntax-wise) how to get/add/edit the kwargs of `photo`.

I've tried `self.fields['photo'].kwargs`, `self.fields['photo'].getattr('width')` and many other similar constructions that I've used in the past, but none provided any results.

After some googling I stumbled upon `x = kwargs.pop('y', None)` (it's not the same as `list.pop()`, is it?), but was unable to find any documentation on that and overall I get the feeling, that when I call `kwargs.pop(x, y)` in the `save()` method, then it handles the kwargs of the `save()` method, no matter what I set for `x` and `y`.

A little help or a hint in the right direction would be much appreciated guys, been stuck with this for days now. :)

PS. I am well aware of [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) and also well aware of that it fails to function with some specific generic Django views.

Comment: `kwargs` in most contexts is a dictionary. See the python documentation for dictionaries. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict  If you call `.pop`, it will remove that item from the dictionary, if it exists

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Those kwargs are for the field definition, they're not something you'd change per instance.

Comment: Yes. It may not be the right way to do it, but what I want to accomplish has to be possible. Basically I just have to give `CustomImageField` parameters `width` and `height` between defining the field and creating an actual instance. If there's another good way to do it, I would be most thankful.